# Fade transition on page breaks when using the browser "back button"

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following script to do a fade in and fade out on page load/exit. It works great, except that when the user clicks the browsers "back" button it breaks leaving the page empty.

I know this is because the script sets my containing `div #mainwrap` to `display: none`.

I just can't work out how to invoke the script when the user clicks the browser back button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mainwrap").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#mainwrap").fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        jQuery("#mainwrap").fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to execute code further if one clicks the back button?

Comment: Because if the user clicks the back button it breaks the page they return to (Provided it's a page on my site), thus the user gets a white screen of nothing (because CSS is set to display: none).